# How to process remaining data in the BlockingCollection<> when CompleteAdding() has been called

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, concurrency, producer-consumer

`BlockingCollection<>` ignores to process remaining data in the underlying queue when receives a call from `CompleteAdding()` method. The following code, is part of the consumer's method:

```
while (blockingCollection.TryTake(out item Item))
{
    //Do something with item.
}
```

Instead, I'd like to change it in a way that it processes all the remaining items **AFTER** producer issues `CompleteAdding()` method, and **ONLY THEN** jumps out from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** the correct way to consume a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1):

```
while (blockingCollection.TryTake(out item Item))
{
    // Do something with item
}
```

The above loop exits at any moment the `blockingCollection` is temporarily out of items. The correct way is to enumerate the [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable):

```
foreach (var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    // Do something with item
}
```

The above loop exits when the `blockingCollection` has been marked as `CompleteAdding`, and all available items have been processed. If at any moment the `blockingCollection` is temporarily empty, the loop blocks the current thread, waiting synchronously for either a new item or for the `CompleteAdding()` signal.

A more specialized loop variant is presented below. In case of inactivity it logs a message every few seconds, so that you know that the consumer is not dead but just idle.

```
while (true)
{
    while (blockingCollection.TryTake(out item Item, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    {
        // Do something with item
    }
    if (blockingCollection.IsCompleted) break;

    // Log a heartbeat
}
```